# How to use tf.data's initializable iterators within a tf.estimator's input_fn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I would like to manage my training with a [`tf.estimator.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) but have some trouble to use it alongside the [`tf.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data) API.

I have something like this:

```
def model_fn(features, labels, params, mode):
  # Defines model's ops.
  # Initializes with tf.train.Scaffold.
  # Returns an tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec.

def input_fn():
  dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset("test.txt")
  # map, shuffle, padded_batch, etc.

  iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

  return iterator.get_next()

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn)
estimator.train(input_fn)
```

As I can't use a `make_one_shot_iterator` for my use case, my issue is that `input_fn` contains an iterator that should be initialized within `model_fn` (here, I use [`tf.train.Scaffold`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/train/Scaffold) to initialize local ops).

Also, I understood that we can't only use `input_fn = iterator.get_next` otherwise the other ops will not be added to the same graph.

What is the recommended way to initialize the iterator?

Comment: @guillaumeklin -- did you add `tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TABLE_INITIALIZERS, iterator.initializer)` within the input_fn()?

Comment: Yes, you can add this line in `input_fn()` just before `return iterator.get_next()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of TensorFlow 1.5, it is possible to make `input_fn` return a `tf.data.Dataset`, e.g.:

```
def input_fn():
  dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset("test.txt")
  # map, shuffle, padded_batch, etc.
  return dataset
```

See [c294fcfd](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/c294fcfd85c03a801d3aad83cfd08055dadbad1a).

---

For previous versions, you can add the iterator's initializer in the `tf.GraphKeys.TABLE_INITIALIZERS` collections and rely on the default initializer.

```
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TABLE_INITIALIZERS, iterator.initializer)
```

Comment: Thanks! +1. Just to clarify the answer: need to add the `tf.add_to_collection...` line before returning `input_fn()`  and then it works fine and don't need to do anything with `Scaffold` and `local_init_ops`.

Comment: Excuse me, is it possible to specify names for each field of the dataset using the first method? For example, my dataset has 2 fields: "age" and "sex", and I want to return a dictionary looks like: {"age": tensor1, "sex": tensor2}.

Comment: @Pekka @guillaumekln did you add the `tf.add_to_collection(...)` line within the `def input_fn()` or elsewhere within the `model_fn()`? If this was added in the `model_fn()` then would the line still be `tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TABLE_INITIALIZERS, iterator.initializer)` or would iterator.initializer need to be changed to something else?

Comment: You should add it in `input_fn()`, just after the creation of the iterator.